# Mysql query for following requirement

Tags: mysql

Database Schema :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS salespersons, orders, orderlines, products; 
CREATE TABLE salespersons(salespersonid INT,NAME CHAR(8)); 
INSERT INTO salespersons VALUES(1,'Sam'),(2,'Xavier'); 
CREATE TABLE orders(orderid INT,salespersonid INT); 
INSERT INTO orders VALUES(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,2),(5,2); 
CREATE TABLE orderlines(lineid INT,orderid INT,productid INT,qty INT); 
INSERT INTO orderlines VALUES(1,1,1,1),(2,1,1,2),(3,2,2,1),(4,3,1,1),(5,4,1,1),(6,5,2,2); 
CREATE TABLE products(productid INT,NAME CHAR(32)); 
INSERT INTO products VALUES(1,'computer desk'),(2,'lamp'),(3,'desk chair');
```

> Question :

Wants to retrieve product list, i.e.products which is sold by all sellers.

Expected Output :

[image]

I created following query,

```
SELECT 
   p1.`name`  AS productList
FROM
  `products` AS p1 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      p.`productid`,
      COUNT(DISTINCT (s.`salespersonid`)) AS productSellers,
      (SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
      FROM
        salespersons) AS totalSeller 
    FROM
      `products` AS p 
      INNER JOIN orderlines AS ol 
        ON p.`productid` = ol.`productid` 
      INNER JOIN orders AS o 
        ON ol.`orderid` = o.`orderid` 
      INNER JOIN salespersons AS s 
        ON o.`salespersonid` = s.`salespersonid` 
    GROUP BY p.`productid` 
    HAVING productSellers = totalSeller) AS ps 
    ON p1.`productid` = ps.productid 
    WHERE ps.productid IS NOT NULL;
```

It is giving correct result but I a not sure if its standard way of writing query for such question.

If anyone know better way to write query for this question then please suggest

Comment: is it performing poorly?

Comment: Yes, performance is also going down with large data as there are joins in inner query.

I am more concerned about query creation, Wants to know standard way of writing query for such conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic approach is fine.  You are comparing the number of sales people who sold a product to the total number of sales people.  However, your query can be simplified:

```
SELECT p.Name
FROM products p INNER JOIN
     orderlines ol 
     ON p.productid = ol.productid INNER JOIN
     orders o 
     ON ol.orderid = o.orderid 
GROUP BY p.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.salespersonid) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM salespersons);
```

Here are the changes:

- You don't need the additional join to `products`.  All the work is done in the subquery, it just has to return the values that you want.
- You don't need to join to the `SalesPerson` table (unless there is the possibility that `o.SalesPersonId` could be invalid).  You can just take the column from `orders`.
- You can put expressions in the `HAVING` clause instead of using column aliases.

As a matter of preference, I also removed the backticks and the `as` from the table aliases.  I find the backticks make the query harder to read.  I only use (and always) use `as` for column aliases but find them unnecessary for table aliases.

Comment: Points explained is very helpful.

Comment: I am using sqlyog (mysql GUI tool), this require table aliases to get table fields , thats why I usually do table aliases.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a couple of the joins as they seem unnecessary

```
SELECT 
   p1.`name`  AS productList
FROM
  `products` AS p1 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      ol.`productid`,
      COUNT(DISTINCT (o.`salespersonid`)) AS productSellers,
      (SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
      FROM
        salespersons) AS totalSeller 
    FROM
      orderlines AS ol 
      INNER JOIN orders AS o 
        ON ol.`orderid` = o.`orderid`  
    GROUP BY ol.`productid` 
    HAVING productSellers = totalSeller) AS ps 
    ON p1.`productid` = ps.productid 
    WHERE ps.productid IS NOT NULL;
```

Here is a SQLFiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4aa66/5

Outside of that, if you need better performance, just add indexes where it makes sense. A good place to start would be on the columns you are joining on, but understand this can cause extra overhead when updating/inserting/deleting records.